# Does Google provide material design resources?

Tags: website-design, google-material-design

Does Google provide Material Design building blocks for designers (i.e. ready to use components as psd files)? I haven't found any in the specs.

Answer (score 5):

Google doesn't provide ready made PSDs, no, but they provide better things.

Check out Google's [Material Design Specifications](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) which is packed with all sorts of guidelines of how to design in a material way, from the style and layout to usability and animations.

If you're looking for help on the coding/implementation side, you can check out [Material Design Lite](http://www.getmdl.io/), a starter pack of sorts. Check out the [blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/introducing-material-design-lite-3ce67098c031) for more information. Google has also released some ready-made templates using MDL which can be found [here](http://www.getmdl.io/templates/index.html).

For general information regarding Google's Material Design, check out [their page for it](https://www.google.com/design/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think google offers any "ready to use" PSDs but you can find some free PSD provided by other users [here](http://materialdesignblog.com/top-10-free-material-design-psd-templates-and-ui-kits/)

If you need some inspiration in Material Design, google has a page for that https://www.google.com/design/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to some resources for psd templates.

[material design resources](http://materialdesignblog.com/top-10-free-material-design-psd-templates-and-ui-kits/)

Comment: Useful resource, but I'm not fully sure that's actually created by Google

Comment: After some extensive research I have not found my findings to be a valid GMD resource. I have posted on the Google Material design facebook page but received no answer. Hope that you find something that will be of use for your project.